# Is it possible to convert an IPA from Enterprise to Ad Hoc?

Tags: ios, ipa

I have an IPA with Enterprise distribution (ProvisionsAllDevices=true), and I would like to distribute it to some testers using an ad hoc distribution. There is a way to convert it? I don't have the sources, so I can't export it form the Organizer window.

Comment: I don't understand the minus point received. We work with third party developers and we receive test with an enterprise provisioning (unprotected). Sometimes we need to send the app to external people for checking, but we don't want to do it in an unprotected way. There is nothing wrong about it IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have access to the original source in Xcode, it is possible to resign the ipa using different Certificates/Provisioning Profile:

http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/

http://codingtopher.co.uk/search/resign

Comment: By the way, finally I was able to do it using floatsign.sh script, very useful. https://gist.github.com/mediabounds/1367348